# How do I get the current Date in C#

Tags: c#, reporting

I am using the Reporting feature in Visual Studio and I need to create a prop/variable to store the current date so I can display it on my form. I cannot seem to find the proper way to do this in the report view.

I originally tried a property of :

```
public DateTime CurrentDate {get;}
```

This did not work because there is no setter for it. To fix the problem I :

```
public DateTime CurrentDate{get{return DateTime.Now;}}
```

Thanks for the suggestions. They lead me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the propper way? Is DateTime.Now not ok?

Comment: I would recommend to use DateTime.UtcNow for storage instead of DateTime.Now. This makes it more easy to compare with other entries. If you display you should convert it to the local time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx

Comment: I tried using this and I get an error that says: Accessor must declare a body because 'property' is not marked as abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both 'get' and 'set' accessors.

Comment: Have you tried the examples from the MSDN? Please provide us with some source on what you did so far

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
DateTime.Now
```

You can specify format

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yourFormat")
```

Msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For the `Date` only, I would use

DateTime.Today

or

DateTime.Now.Date

Comment: +1 because for some reason, I trust DateTime.Now.Date more than I trust DateTime.Today

Answer (score 0):

System.DateTime.Now.
to get string format:

System.DateTime.Now.ToString()